# JQuery collapsing/expanding need to calculate height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm nearly there, I just need to calculate the height of the hidden children height and apply it to the div.

I probably need to write a function that dynamically changes based of the height of the children.

On the demo, click on the Expand/collapse image.

CLICK EXPAND

```
var currentHeight = $('.Tile.is-expanded .Tile-flyout').outerHeight();

 TweenMax.fromTo(".Tile.is-expanded .Tile-flyout", 0.8, { height:0, autoAlpha:0,   ease: Linear.easeNone }, { height:currentHeight, autoAlpha:1,});
 TweenMax.fromTo(".Tile.is-expanded .Tile-flyout > *", 0.8, {height:0, ease: Linear.easeNone }, {height:"auto"});
```

CLICK COLLAPSE

```
var currentHeightOpen = $('.Tile .Tile-flyout').outerHeight();

  TweenMax.fromTo(".Tile .Tile-flyout", 0.8, { height:currentHeightOpen, autoAlpha:1, ease: Linear.easeNone }, {height:0, autoAlpha:0,});
  TweenMax.fromTo(".Tile .Tile-flyout > *", 0.8, { height:"auto",  ease: Linear.easeNone }, {height:0,});
```

[DEMO here, you need to fork it](https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/gXzPEw?editors=0010)

Comment: What's not working? It looks ok to me?

Comment: did you try to click the close button? its all over the place, doesn't collapse at all

Comment: It does for me... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: have a look this demo https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/gXzPEw?editors=0010

Comment: Yeah that one dont work. The link in your post does

Comment: even the other one wasn't collapsing it properly .

Comment: I found it collapsing and 'expanding' correctly, but it didn't expand, just plopped the hidden-now-visible elements on top of the elements below it, making a hard to read jumble. And clicking the 'x' to collapse would just end up clicking the element that it was next to, so immediately expand that element while collapsing the previous one.

Comment: @TylerDahle so what would you do?

Comment: @TylerDahle I think the only way to have this fixed is by controlling the height. so I can push nicely the content below

Comment: Is that what you are after? You want the 'expanded' now visible elements to push the rows of other stuff down below them? Or did you want them to lay on top of everything below better?

Comment: @TylerDahle illiterately like now except when expand it should push smoothly the other divs with its height. and when you click close it'll do the same

Comment: It works the first time, then the second+ times you expand it, it gets the height (which is 2px due to the border, otherwise 0px...), and goes from 0, to the height (2px), instead of the full height. When I hardcoded 478 to the height it goes to, it works fine. Because you are going from height 0 to full height, instead of display none to display block... you can't get calculate height until you fully expand that div. You could count the children, figure out how many lines it will have, then figure out height that way.

Comment: @TylerDahle would you be able to help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Code pen with how to do what I explain in my comments on your main post:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqLREK?editors=0010

```
function(code){ //Ignore this, I apparently need code to link codepen
    //code code
}
```

You will notice, that in the expand, I grab a list of all the child elements you will be expanding and making visible, I then loop through, and for every 3 I add the cell block height to the running height of the items (because we have 3 per line).

**Note, if there can be more or less than 3 per line, you may have to do something to determine this and adjust the loop increment accordingly**

Comment: the codePen is the same as mine, you need to fork it and save it.,

Comment: thanks but I don't see any improvement from mine. I'm still seeing the collapsing jumping. it's ok, on expanding though

Comment: Well, to be fair, yours didn't expand correctly at all (except the first time). And I thought that was the issue? I didn't gather that you must be referring to not seeing the animation on collapse?

Comment: sorry, I appreciated your help and sorry If I didn't explain myself. I'm just trying my hardest here but I'm not a guru and I'm struggling

Comment: Updated my answer, all I did was removed your currentHeightOpen. Just use the current height we already calculated above it. The currentHeightOpen was 0 (same as your problem with expanding), so it was going from 0 to 0, so you didn't see an animation.